# Python visibility to pass in function

Tags: python

In A.py

```
class A
  blah = some_fun(d)      <----- needs d
  def __init__
  def a
  def b

def c
  def d                 <---- d is inside c
```

is it possible to pass in d because currently `blah` cannot see d for obvious reasons?

Comment: You're saying that `c` is a function (not a class), and `d` is a function defined within that function? Then no, not unless there's a `return d` statement in `c`.

Comment: Please fix your code first so it at least _compiles_

Comment: thats exactly what i am saying. @DavidRobinson thats what i was afraid of. i suppose i put d outside of c and pass in d to c then blah can see d

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
def c():
    def d():
        pass
    return d

blah = some_fun(c())
```

Comment: it is a way but c needs to return something else as it is for other purpose than returning the func d. but i suppose its my fault for being too generic with the Q

Comment: @ealeon If you can't return `d`, then make `d` an attribute of `c` or create a new function or better make it a static method inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define class `A` inside the function `c`, in which case it will be able to see `d` (assuming `d` is defined first).  Then you might need to pass out `A` from the function so that outsiders can use it.

Something about this smells like you are solving the wrong problem for the real task at hand.  Perhaps you could clarify your question and/or give a more concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class A
  blah = some_fun(d)
  def __init__
  def a
  def b

def c
  global d
  def d                 <---- d is now global
```

Comment: blah is static to class and not attached to individual object of A

Comment: how about with the new changes?